# Can I setup VS10 to notify me when a build was unexpected interrupted?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation

I work on a project that takes 2-3 minuts to compile. Usually when I add some code I run it for testing and then tab to something else because I not going to watch it being compiled for 2 minuts everytime.

Sometimes I get a compile error.

I would like to get notified when that happen (the build was interrupted and no website was opened) to safe time.

Is it possible to tell VS10 that it can play a little "beep"-sound or focus VS10 window or something, so I can carry on right away?

I'm guessing there ain't and maybe I just have to get used to not have the other window in fullscreen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is already provided.  Control Panel + Sound, Sounds tab.  Scroll down in the Program events list and locate the Microsoft Visual Studio group.  Assign sounds to the "Build Failed" and "Build Succeeded" events.

Comment: That's a nice feature. Thank you very much. Life is good now. I'll accept when I can't in 3 minuts...

Comment: I can add that the features is: "Breakpoint Hit", "Build Canceled", "Build Failed", "Build Succeeded". I'm going to use them all for sure :)